# Passing argument 3 of “fgets ” from incompatible pointer type

Tags: c, arrays, fgets

I have a warning on my program and I don't know how to solve this. First I have the warning `passing argument 3 of "fgets" from incompatible pointer type`. Here is my program:

```
bool get_name(char name[],char buff[])
{

    if(isalpha(buff))
    {
    fgets(name,sizeof(MAXNAME),buff);
    return name;
    }
    else
    {
            return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: how [this](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) did not help?

Comment: The third argument to [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) is a `FILE *`.  You must have opened the file (successfully) with [`fopen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fopen.html) before you can use `fgets()` to read it.  Note that `sizeof(MAXNAME)` is probably 4.  You should pass the size of the buffer to your function.  Also, you probably have `name` where you should have `buff` and you need `fp` where you have `buff` — in the call to `fgets()`, I mean.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I have been looking at documentation for a while now, but im not sure what im exactly doing incorrectly

Comment: Having said all that, it is not clear why you're using `fgets()`.  That is a function that reads a line (or as much of a line as it can) from a file.  If you're extracting a string from another string, you do _not_ need `fgets()` at all.

Comment: @AdamDoe In that case, I have posted an answer, it was a bit lengthy for a comment box.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler alright, thank you for your help. Im still confused about fp.  I am not passing in a file pointer so is what your saying is that i Should do the following? 
    fgets(buff,sizeof(MAXNAME),fp);

Comment: Is the token meant to be alphabetic, alphanumeric, or start with alphabetic and continue with alphanumerics (like an identifier)?  Does `_` count as either alphabetic or alphanumeric?

Comment: I'm saying you should not be using `fgets()` at all — the problem description is about string manipulation, not file I/O.

Comment: yes it is supposed to start alaphabetic and continue to be alphabetic basically it is trying to identify if the name inputted is actually a name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the task description:

- copy a string starting with an alphabetic character and continuing with alphanumeric characters from `buff` to `name`

the code should not be using `fgets()` at all.  (See the comments to the question for discussion of what would be necessary if `fgets()` was relevant.)  The code should be something like:

```
bool get_name(char name[], char buff[])
{
    if (isalpha(buff[0]))
    {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; isalnum(buff[i]); i++)
            name[i] = buff[i];
        name[i] = '\0';
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        name[0] = '\0';
        return false;
    }
}
```

This code assumes that `name` is big enough to hold any identifier that is in `buff`.  Note that the `isalnum(buff[i])` test will pass when `i` is 0, but the value checked will always be alphabetic because of the outer test.

#### Example program

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

extern bool get_name(char name[], char buff[]);

bool get_name(char name[], char buff[])
{
    if (isalpha(buff[0]))
    {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; isalnum(buff[i]); i++)
            name[i] = buff[i];
        name[i] = '\0';
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        name[0] = '\0';
        return false;
    }
}

#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static void test(char *buffer)
{
    char name[64];

    if (get_name(name, buffer))
        printf("Got name [%s] from [%s]\n", name, buffer);
    else
    {
        printf("No name in [%s]\n", buffer);
        assert(name[0] == '\0');
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char buffer1[] = "Adelson23 and all that!";
    char buffer2[] = "=not an identifier=";

    test(buffer1);
    test(buffer2);
    return 0;
}
```

#### Example output

```
Got name [Adelson23] from [Adelson23 and all that!]
No name in [=not an identifier=]
```

Answer (score 2):

***To answer the question in the title***

From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) for `fgets()`, the signature is

> `char *fgets(char *s, int size, FILE *stream)`

where, the third argument is of type `FILE *`. You cannot pass a `char *` there.

Also, to quote the `C11`, chapter 7.21.7.2

> The `fgets` function reads at most one less than the number of characters specified by `n`
>   **from the stream pointed to by `stream`** into the array pointed to by `s`. [...]

So, it has to be a *stream*, not a file name in form of a `char` array or something.

---

***Note:***

As mentioned rightly by [Mr. Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) in the comments, from the problem description, it does not look like you need to use `fgets()` in your code, at all. Please break down the problem statement into an algorithm in pen and paper first to clear out the confusion, then come back and re-write the code.

Comment: Although correct, this is addressing a red herring, I fear.  If you manage to plough through the verbiage, it is moderately clear that the function in the question should not be trying to use `fgets()` at all.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler you're very right sir, I was mostly concentrating on the question title alone. After reading your comments in the question and here, I got the picture. Let me edit my answer to clarify that, too. :)